# Why are there tons of users listed in Windows 10?

Tags: users

I'm having some file permission issues trying to install Drupal on Xampp, when I click on users, I see 5 of them in permissions, but there is only one user account, admin, me.

Why so many users, can I delete some?

One of them says "unknown"...I have no idea what it's doing there and the others also!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Account Unknown refers to an account that used to exist but has been deleted. It can also refer to a deleted usergroup.

The SYSTEM account is part of windows and is required for certain programs to work normally. The system account has the highest privileges and is fully controlled by windows.

The other 3 are groups and contain users. Depending on the rights of your user, it may be only in the Users group, or in both, and will also be in Authenticated Users if the user account has a password and was logged in using that password.

Answer (score 2):

If you read the label for the list, you'll notice the caption is "Group and User names" not simply users.

A user will be part of various groups to control access. For example your account, being the only user and an Admin should be part of groups "Users", "Authenticated Users" and "Administrators".

But Windows will also require access to the folder, so the System Account has access.

Finally, the "Unknown Account" is a [Microsoft Well Known SID](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/243330/well-known-security-identifiers-in-windows-operating-systems), and is not a problem:

```
SID: S-1-16-4096
Name: Low Mandatory Level
Description: A low integrity level.

Note Added in Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008
```